# ASPNET50/ASPNETCORE50 compiler directives ignored in MVC5 web application

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I created a new ASP.Net 5 web application using the VS2015 template.
Why would the compiler directive be ignored ?

[image: as shown here]

I am following Scott Allen's "ASP.Net 5 First Look" course on Pluralsight. He is using the beta in the course, but i can't see why this would have changed.

I can see that the Solution DNX SDK Version is 1.0.0-rc1-update1

Comment: It means the symbols `ASPNET50` and `ASPNETCORE50` are not defined. Try `DNX451` and `DNXCORE50` instead https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/3.

Comment: @Jasen that is the answer. Care to put it as such.

Comment: One of the returns will show as disabled depending on which runtime is selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the symbols `ASPNET50` and `ASPNETCORE50` are not defined. Try `DNX451` and `DNXCORE50` instead.

https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/3.